# Loading balancing between trading engines

Tags: linux, memory-management, load-balancing, algorithmic-trading

In our current setup, we have "`n`"-trading engines, spread across multiple hosts and a load balancer, which sends the incoming order to one of the engines, which have the capacity.

Previously, the trading engines were 32-bit Linux processes and the capacity was calculated based on the `RSS` of the process, `VSZ` limit, and the engine lag (the time difference between the wall clock time and the trading engine time).

Now, we are migrating to a 64-bit process. I'm thinking of a good heuristic to calculate the capacity.

Given how Linux manages memory of processes ( with over commit on ), the `RSS` of the process can be quite high, due to the availability of large RAM sizes and the un-used pages might not be swapped out.

I'm inclining towards dropping memory of the process from calculating the available capacity. Instead, to rely only on the engine lag.

In addition to lag, to also look into the memory utilization of the host, to decide whether any trading engines should be picked from that host to handle the new order.

I would like to know your thoughts and tips on how you solved this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear: are you working on the exchange side or the customer side?  In other words, are you receiving orders and matching them, or are you generating orders and sending them to an exchange?  What's an approximate value of "n"?

Comment: generating orders and sending them to an exchange. n is usually 10.

Comment: What are your **success-metrics?** What are target levels of **Latency [us]** introduced by such load-balancer handling? What are target production levels of **TPS performance**? What are target levels of **failure robustness / resilience** with respect to keeping both non-deteriorated TPS performance & Latency envelopes? What are your Project budget / time-to-market / DevOps-capacities constraints for implementing & turning a target solution into production state in due time & fashion?